# RxJava compile error on the following case

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I would like to try the very simple RxJava code like the following

```
 int[] test = {1,2,3,4};
 Observable<Integer> findAverage = Observable.fromArray(test);
 averageInteger(findAverage).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

First I met a compile error(incompitible bounds) for the Observeable.fromArray(test),

Second, it seems severageInteger can no longer be found. I am using 2.0.8 version of RxJava.

Comment: You need at least `Integer[] test = {1, 2, 3, 4};` because primitive arrays are not supported by RxJava itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the wrong type of findAverage:

It should be:

```
Observable<int[]> observable = Observable.fromArray(array);
```

A full example with following Gradle-package: *'com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.16.4'*

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.fromIterable(integers);

Observable<Double> doubleObservable = MathObservable.averageDouble(integerObservable);

doubleObservable.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Implement as Operator:

```
@Test
public void averageDoubleOperator() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

    Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.fromIterable(integers);

    integerObservable.lift(new AvgOperator())
            .test()
            .assertResult(2.5);
}

@Test
public void averageDoubleOperator_empty() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> integers = Collections.emptyList();

    Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.fromIterable(integers);

    integerObservable.lift(new AvgOperator())
            .test()
            .assertTerminated()
            .assertError(IllegalStateException.class);
}

class Avg {
    long count;
    int sum;

    Avg(long count, int sum) {
        this.count = count;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}

class AvgOperator implements ObservableOperator<Double, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Observer<? super Integer> apply(Observer<? super Double> observer) throws Exception {
        return new Operation(observer);
    }

    class Operation implements Observer<Integer> {
        private final Observer<? super Double> observer;
        private Subscription s;
        private long sum;
        private int count;

        Operation(Observer<? super Double> observer) {
            this.observer = observer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            observer.onSubscribe(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            ++count;
            sum = sum + integer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            this.observer.onError(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            if (count == 0) {
                this.onError(new IllegalStateException("Average is not defined for 0 values."));
                return;
            }
            this.observer.onNext(sum / (double) count);
            this.observer.onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like  MathObservable is from rxjava-math which is not supported by rxjava2

Comment: As stated the MathObservable is taken from rxjava2-extensions, because it is not supported in native rxjava2. You could copy the implementation of MathObservable or write your own using reduce operator.